# Prometheus - many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Hi I am trying to monitor fortigate Firewalls using the dashboard specified in https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7567

This works fine with a single target, however as soon as I add another target in the Prometheus.yml file, my grafana dashboard panels error with

```
many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side
```

My job in Prometheus.yml config looks like this:

```
  - job_name: 'snmp-exporter'
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - XX.XX.XX.XX
        - YY.YY.YY.YY
    scrape_interval: 1m
    scrape_timeout : 1m
    metrics_path: /snmp
    params:
      module: [fortigate_snmp]
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: localhost:9116
```

Comment: Can you identify the request that triggers the error ?

Comment: topk(10,irate( ifHCInOctets{instance=~"$instance"}[5m]) * on (ifIndex) group_left(ifName) ifName)

The ifname for XX.XX.XX.XX and YY.YY.YY.YY are the same - port1, port2 and port3. Hence, what I think is happening is in the tsdb there are two groups of port1, port2 and port3. Not sure why should this happen because I am trying to query by instance.